# if statement with every alterable arguments

Tags: javascript

Question is in comment:

```
function test(arrOfObj) {
    var test = "TEST: there is val1, there is val2, but there is NO v3 and v4"; // our test string

    if (test.indexOf("TEST:") !== -1) {
        // ok this is our string to test
        arrOfObj.forEach(function(item) {
            for (key in item) {
                if (test.indexOf(item[key]) !== -1) {
                    console.log(
                        " Hurrayyy " + item[key] + " value is inside test!"
                    ); // ok the values are matched correctly in "test" string
                }
            }
        });
    }

    var test = "val1, val2, val4 - no v3";
    // but now lets suposse I want to make an IF statement for different string where only SOME othe array values can exist
    // - so lets supose that we have a match at val1, val2, val4 and I want to cover them all in ONE if statemnt with OR logical operator:
    if (
        test.indexOf([i1] - val1) !== -1 ||
        test.indexOf([i2 - val2]) !== -1 ||
        test.indexOf([i4 - val4]) !== -1
    ) {
        // do something then
    }
    // how to do that?**
}
test([{ prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2", prop3: "val3", prop4: "val4" }]); // we pass an array with object that has many properties
```

Comment: please add a description of the problem you have, what you have tried and the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand it all, but I think you talk about this kind of solution:

```
let items = [
  {
    'a': 'val1',
    'b': 'val2',
    'c': 'val3',
  },
  {
    'd': 'val4'
  }
]

function test(array) {
  var str = 'TEST: there is val1, there is val2, but there is NO v3 and val4';

  array.forEach((item) => {
    if (Object.values(item).reduce((prev, cur) => prev || str.indexOf(cur) !== -1, false)) {
      console.log("YES")
    }
  });
}

test(items);
```

In this example, keys (a, b, c) are linked with logical OR. So we check this:

First iteration:

is val1 in str OR is val2 in str OR is val3 in str

Second iteration:

is val4 in str

I hope my explanations are not too bad :)

Comment: Nice! Way better then my own idea with eval(). Now I need to understand it and mutate. Thanks!

Comment: hmm one question thought - why did you set false as a initial value (you could just pass it out)?

Comment: ok, so setting it (initial value) as 'false' is just like not pass it at all, right? Thanks, again!

Comment: Wonderful explanation, got it. Could you answer one more question I asked here - https://jsfiddle.net/tqbrm0y9/ ?? You can always mail me at: prostyler@protonmail.com if you don't want/can't  answer here.

Comment: Sorry, I said something wrong (it happens :'D). In this case, as you transform the datatype through the reduce function (from string to boolean), the initial value is necessary. Why? Just because the reduce first iteration will set the accumulator as the first item of the array you're reducing. So, if your reduce function is (acc || str.indexOf(cur) !== -1) JS will evaluate your string as "true" (because acc variable is not undefind or null). Sorry again, hope my answer will be clear for you

Answer (score 0):

You have array of objects as argument so you need a loop over the array, if you want to pick first one use `arrOfObj[0]`.

You need something like this:

```
var obj = arrOfObj[0]; // first object
var values = Object.values(obj); // array of string - only 'val1', 'val2' ...

if (test.indexOf(values[0]) !== -1 || test.indexOf(values[1]) !== -1 || test.indexOf(values[2]) !== -1) {

}
```

but this can be simplified with regex:

```
var values = Object.values(arrOfObj[0]);
var re = new RegExp(values.join('|'));
if (test.test(re)) {

}
```

Comment: yea but the thing is that I need to build this IF statement with OR for unknown length of the arrOfObj, so if the array has 2 object property I need to have one || - if there is 5 properties I need to have 4 || - with every property of arrOfObj inside this IF.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(arrOfObj)
{
  var test = 'TEST: there is val1, there is val2, but there is NO v3 and v4'; // our test string

  if (test.indexOf('TEST:') !== -1)
  {
    var ev = '';
    var counter = 0;

    arrOfObj.forEach(function(item)
    {
      for (key in item)
      {
        if (test.indexOf(item[key]) !== -1)
        {
          counter = counter + 1;
          if (counter <= 1)
          {
            ev = ev + '(test.indexOf("' + item[key] + '") !== -1)'
            ev = eval(ev);
          }
          else
          {
            ev = ev + ' || (test.indexOf("' + item[key] + '") !== -1)'
            ev = eval(ev);
          }
        }
      }
    });

    var ifStatement = eval(ev);
    if (ifStatement)
    {
      console.log('BAM!');
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('BUM!');
    }
  }
}
test([{prop1:'val1', prop2:'val2', prop3:'val3', prop4:'val4'}]); // we pass an array with object that has many properties
```

But eval() i evil... so @Imaguest ansver is better.